# julia : setting a variable in anonymous function so that it is set forever and you can evaluate in other variables only

Tags: julia, anonymous-function

So for demonstration, lets say I have a function f(x,y), where y is going to be fixed for all evaluations of f.

```
my_func = x -> f(x,y)
```

My question is I believe that when you evaluate my_func(x) it will rerun f(x,y) again and again for every x you evaluate it at. I don't want to have to reconstruct f every time I have a new x, because y is fixed. Is there any way that I can make one evaluation of f(x,y) happen for a fixed y and x is not determined yet, i.e make a g(x)= f(x,y) (because y is fixed)?

So then I can just have

```
my_func2 = x-> g(x)
```

so that I am just evaluating it for some given x.

Thank you.

Comment: You mean like `f(x, y=y) = x + y` for normal functions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you mean. But if you do `g(x) = f(x, y)`, and you make sure `y` is a `const`, then you will not pay any penalty relative to just evaluating `f(x, y)`, and indeed `g(x)` may be even simpler since the compiler knows `y` is a constant. Julia will spend no extra time "reconstructing f".

If you're asking "how do I prevent spending time calculating `f(x, y)` for repeated values of `x` and `y`", the answer is to use [memoization](https://github.com/JuliaCollections/Memoize.jl), i.e. caching previous computations.

Comment: One could in principle use [Mjolnir and IRTools](https://github.com/FluxML/Mjolnir.jl/blob/master/examples/futamura/futamura.ipynb) to evaluate partially evaluated IR for `f`. But that goes way over the head of the question, I guess.